# successful ajax call not returning to success function

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am working on a .NET Core MVC application, I have added JavaScript code in a partial view, the JavaScript code is hitting function of controller but it is not hitting success function of Ajax call.
Below is my JavaScript code, code is executing on page load

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("getMenurights","Home")',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: OnSuccessMenuRights,
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }

            });
            
        });
    </script>
```

controller code:-

```
     public string getMenuRights()
     {
        string result = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId")as string))
        {

            Home objHome = new Home();
            DataTable dtMenuRights = new DataTable();
            dtMenuRights = objHome.GetMenuRights(HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId").ToString());
            List<DataRow> MenuList = dtMenuRights.AsEnumerable().ToList();

            TempData["MenuRights"] = dtMenuRights;
            if (MenuList.Count > 0)
            {
                ViewBag.MenuList = MenuList;
            }
            TempData.Keep("MenuRights");
            //var x = TempData["MenuRights"];
            JsonSerializerSettings jss = 
            new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling =ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };
            result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtMenuRights, Formatting.Indented, jss);
        
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Share the success function body as well. Also, first of all try to write a function directly in success, similar like u wrote in error. And check what is coming in response data. Dont not use alert , instead use console.log

Comment: What is your status code ?
What do you get id fail function data ?

Comment: you may want to check the error with:  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
           errortext = error + jqXHR.responseText; alert(errortext); }  (Instead of "failure: ")

Comment: i am getting null in error string,also status is 500 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is not hitting success function of Ajax call

Based on your code, we can find that your action method `getMenuRights()` return a plain text string to consumer, you can modify the `dataType` option to `'text'`, like below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("getMenurights","Home")',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: OnSuccessMenuRights,
    failure: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }

});
```

Besides, to troubleshoot Ajax request related issue, you can try to check the response of that ajax request you made in browser F12 developer tool Network tab. And check if something wrong with the request you made (http 400 error) or server side (http 500 error) etc.

Comment: `internal server error 500` that indicates the server encountered an unexpected condition. You can debug your code to check if any exception occur in your action method `getMenuRights`.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

1. You're returning empty string if user has no session. `jQuery`, as of 1.9, rejects empty responses. The response should be `null` or `{}`, not empty string. It also rejects malformed `JSON` but unlikely in this case since you're using a library to generate `JSON`.
2. It could be because your return type is `string`, thus `Content-Type` header becomes `text/plain`. Try using either one of these

- Use `dataType: 'text json'` in your `jQuery` call. This will tell jQuery to treat text as `JSON`.
- or return `JSON` instead of `string` from the MVC controller using `JsonResult` as your return type. This should cause `Content-Type` header to be set to `application/json`.

Here is the spec in details (see `dataType`)

https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/